# make it convenient for me , conveniently

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, word-order

> It is convenient for me to receive medical treatment

Is it correct to write: "I receive medical treatment conveniently"?

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: The second one sounds wrong to me, but I'm having trouble explaining exactly why.  I think it's because the first one is stative: the act of receiving treatment *is* convenient.  But the second one says that I receive treatment *in a convenient way*.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> It is convenient for me to receive medical treatment.

means getting the medical treatment is *convenient*, whereas

> I receive medical treatment conveniently.

has more the meaning that the treatment is convenient, for example using pills instead of injections, which has a slightly different meaning, however

> I conveniently receive medical treatment.

has the same meaning as your first sentence.

This is mainly due to positioning relative to the verb.